# Создание карты на сайте

Tags: yandex-maps-jsapi

[image: карта с балунами и маршрутом между ними]

Добрый день,наткнулся на такую карту,хочу внедрять что-то похожее на сайт,но не могу связать разные части кодов из документации Яндекс карт в одну часть,чтобы все работало.Может кто-то выполнял подобное карте на скриноште,чтобы на карте отображались метки(в моем случае из базы данных) и чтобы был путь.буду признателен в помощи

Answer (score 0):

У сервиса Yandex Maps есть [отличная документация богатая примерами](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/3.0/quick-start/index.html).

С решением вашей задачи можно ознакомиться [тут](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/icon_customImage/).
Ссылка ведет на пример, в котором иконка указывается в поле **iconImageHref**

[image: Пример указания ссылки на иконку "пина"]

Answer (score 0):

судя по меткам, тут нарисован пешеходный мультимаршрут (type: pedestrian) с указанием промежуточных тразитных точек, опорные точки можно редактировать как угодно (изучив Placemark)

https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/dg/concepts/router/multiRouter.html

*внизу страницы - пример, как работать с транзитными точками